# How to parse this sentence formally/syntactically?

Tags: american-english, relative-pronouns

"You have a bad day,handicapping" . Can I formally convert it into"you have a bad day, which is handicapping"?

Comment: What is your idea/reason for using "handicapping" in that sentence?

Comment: This is not a complete sentence. What are you trying to say?

Comment: The first might be a complete but not quite idiomatic sentence if it means "When you pick the winners of horse races for a living, you frequently have bad days."

Answer (score 0):

No,I don't think you can."Handicapping "here doesn't refer to the day as you want to show by your transformation. It refers to "you"and describes your actions. You often  have  bad days because of handicapping.But you should have given more context.